# How To Run Webservice Without add web refrence

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I have a Web Service with this property
URL : http:\192.168.0.10/MOI/services/TestService
Parameter : plateNo | userName | password

Return All data on machine Card

All properties are STRING
I Need to run this service and show Return Value on form.
How to run this web service without add web reference

Answer (score 0):

first add web Reference to your project and go through the code that visual studio generate for you, find the method you want to use, copy the code to your own class or method and finally delete the web reference.

Comment: i cant access to webservice on my pc

Comment: Create a web service on your system that you can access with the same name, input and output. and then do the things I said. and at the end change the URL to your actual web service url

Comment: i need call web service using httpwebrequset